# Facebook : access App permissions for each of the user's apps

Tags: facebook

Can anyone tell me ifwe can access the permissions that each application that a user has added is available through Facebook APIs?

The idea is to display to the user, the permissions they have granted to each of the apps they have.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bit old but still unanswered...

yes you can with graph api or facebook query language

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/

Comment: hm, probably does not apply to apps outside your own

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can request what specific permission a user has granted your application.